# Como puedo hacer un if con la libreria fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, datatables, fullcalendar

es que desde hace varios días he estado intentando hacer un 'if' con fullcalendar en JavaScript, pero he hecho muchos intentos pero no me ha funcionado nada, también he buscado información pero no he encontrado nada o un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer,
La tabla esta hecha con datatables.

empezaría así, das clic en una columna de la tabla y muestra 'timegridday' pero si le doy clic a otra columna me muestre 'timegridweek'.
si me dan un consejo, me serviría mucho o una manera de como lo puedo empezar.
Gracias

Estos son algunos de los ejemplos que he intentado antes

```
let indexColumn = 2; 
let initialView = indexColumn === 2 ? "timeGridDay" : "timeGridWeek";


var indexColumn = 2;
if (indexColumn === 2) {
    prueba.initialView = "timeGridDay";
} else if (indexColumn === 4) {
    prueba.initialView = "timeGridWeek";
}


var indexColumn = 2;

var prueba = {};

if (indexColumn === 2) {
    prueba.initialView = 'timeGridDay';
} else if (indexColumn !== 2) {
prueba.initialView = 'timeGridWeek';        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que estás tratando de implementar una funcionalidad en la que, al hacer clic en una columna específica en una tabla hecha con DataTables, cambie la vista en FullCalendar. En este caso, quieres que al hacer clic en una columna muestre la vista timeGridDay, y al hacer clic en otra columna muestre la vista timeGridWeek.

Aquí hay un enfoque general de cómo podrías abordar este problema:

1. Agrega un controlador de eventos a las celdas de la columna en la tabla DataTables para capturar los clics.
2. Dentro del controlador de eventos, determina qué columna se ha hecho clic.
3. Basado en la columna clicada, cambia la vista en FullCalendar.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacer esto:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#miTabla').DataTable();

  // Agregar controlador de eventos a las celdas clicables
  $('#miTabla tbody').on('click', '.celda-clicable', function() {
    var columnIndex = table.cell(this).index().column;

    if (columnIndex === 0) {
      cambiarVistaFullCalendar('timeGridDay');
    } else if (columnIndex === 1) {
      cambiarVistaFullCalendar('timeGridWeek');
    }
  });

  function cambiarVistaFullCalendar(vista) {
    // Lógica para cambiar la vista en FullCalendar
    // Por ejemplo, utiliza métodos de FullCalendar para cambiar la vista
    // como: calendar.changeView(vista);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.9/index.global.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="miTabla" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Columna 1</th>
      <th>Columna 2</th>
      <!-- ... otras columnas ... -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="celda-clicable">Contenido 1</td>
      <td class="celda-clicable">Contenido 2</td>
      <!-- ... otras celdas ... -->
    </tr>
    <!-- ... otras filas ... -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ten en cuenta que el código para cambiar la vista en FullCalendar (`cambiarVistaFullCalendar`) dependerá de cómo estés inicializando y utilizando FullCalendar en tu proyecto. Asegúrate de reemplazar la llamada a `cambiarVistaFullCalendar` con la lógica adecuada para cambiar la vista en tu aplicación.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.